# Wordpress x .Net / Javascript Single Sign On SSO

Tags: asp.net, wordpress, woocommerce, single-sign-on, asp.net-ajax

I'm planning to do a front end website in Wordpress (potentially with WooCommerce plugin to handle the membership and subscription side of things). I would also want a social sign on plugin on WP. Let's say this is hosted at www.example.com.

The application/product will be done in ASP.net and will be mostly a single page application heavily reliant on Javascript/Jquery, etc. I want to handle all the account, registration and auth via Wordpress i.e. the user would register, sign in, subscribe and then get access to the .Net product. Let's say this is hosted at app.example.com.

I suspect I can call the WP installation via AJAX. I would need to know 1) is the user signed in and 2) are they authorized. The latter would be reliant on the WooCommerce plugin sharing that info (I guess). if they user wasn't signed in, then they would need to be redirected to the WP sign in page (and then returned again to the product).

I'm not yet sure whether I want to host the Wordpress alongside the .Net in AWS - this is open for consideration. The advantage of hosting together being that the .Net could have direct access to the WP db.

I see at least one other StackOverflow question like this - but it's 10y old. I'm thinking there may be more modern/improved methods. I also see some SSO plugins, but they don't seem to be well used (looking at installs and endorsements).

Comment: HI.  Is there a question here?

Comment: How would I handle the authentication and authorization from the .Net side?